# Enabling CAP_NET_RAW for root users and apps with root permissions on android (Kernel)?

Tags: android, c, linux, kernel

Currently, this is my first time going into kernel modifications and such, so please be gentle with me as I'm learning as I go!

Any who, I've been wanting for some time to allow creation of raw packets for my rooted android phone (nexus 5). I've learned about the AOSP, and started diving into perhaps building the kernel itself to allow the CAP_NET_RAW privilege to the root user, or apps that request root permission.

I've found the functions `extern bool capable(int cap); (<linux/capability.h> and <kernel/capability.c>)`, which calls the function `ns_capable (<linux/capability.h> and <kernel/capability.c>)`. This function is used to check the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability a lot. However, now I'm stuck. Is there a header I can change somewhere, that would allow `CAP_NET_RAW` for the user group that I specify? Or will I need to add code myself to allow for this capability (and if so, has there been anyone who has posted a solution to this before me?).